# overrided method doesn't gets called

Tags: c#, winforms, overriding

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   protected override void  WndProc(ref Message m)
   {
       base.WndProc(ref m);
   }
}

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

When I ran the above code, it called the method `protected override void  WndProc(ref Message m)`

When I changed the code like below

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Application.Run();
```

it didn't call the method `protected override void  WndProc(ref Message m)`

Can any one explain me why is this happening?

Comment: This seemed to be a stupid question :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call Application.Run() you are running the application without a form.

See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx
for the difference.

The top one you are passing your form as a parameter to the Application.Run function call, which allows it to use your form, the second case it has no idea what form to use.

Answer (score 1):

When you call Application.Run() you are running the application without a form.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it, if in the second code sample there is no real Form shown and used in the App?